# How do I wait for a random amount of time before executing the next action in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I would love to be able to wait for a random amount of time (let's say a number between 5-12 seconds, chosen at random each time) before executing my next action in Puppeteer, in order to make the behaviour seem more authentic/real world user-like.

I'm aware of how to do it in plain Javascript (as detailed in the Mozilla docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)), but can't seem to get it working in Puppeteer using the waitFor call (which I assume is what I'm supposed to use?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You are supposed to use waitFor

Comment: Please, show the code you already have, it could be just a typo that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use vanila JS to randomly wait between 5-12 seconds between action.

```
await page.waitFor((Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 5) * 1000)
```

Where:

- `5` is the start number
- `12` is the end number
- `1000` means it's converting seconds to milliseconds

*(PS: However, if you question is about waiting 5-12 seconds randomly before every action, then you should have a class with wrapper, which is a different issue until you update your question.)*

Comment: For me, it will wait beween 5 and 17 seconds. You have to write Math.random() * 7 to have 5-12.